# Delete data records in DHIS 2 Tracker

Tags: dhis2

I have entered test data into the [DHIS 2 Tracker](https://www.dhis2.org/individual-data-records) program. Now I want to delete all test data. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

To remove ALL tracker data from your DHIS2 database run the following sql commands in order:

```
delete from trackedentitydatavalue;
delete from programstageinstance;
delete from programinstance;
delete from trackedentityaudit;
delete from trackedentityattributevalue;
delete from trackedentityinstance;
```

WARNING: This cannot be undone

From https://www.npmjs.com/package/dhis2-tracker-populator